# ng-repeat on subarray not working?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this code:

```js
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    val: 'bleh1',
    subval: [{
      attr1: 1,
      attr2: 2
    },{
      attr1:3,
      attr2:4
    }]
  }, {
    val: 'bleh2',
    subval: [{
      attr1: 1,
      attr2: 2
    },{
      attr1:3,
      attr2:4
    }]
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">
  
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items.subval">
      <div>{{item.attr1}}</div>
      <div>{{item.attr2}}</div>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I've been trying to figure out why the ng-repeat is not working but i have not been able to solve it. I followeb the AngularJS course on CodeSchool and also went through the AngularJS tutorial tho i can't find the error in my code. I've been looking around here as well and could not find a solution either. Can you guys point me what i should look for or what is the mistake i have please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`items` does not have a property called `subval`, since `items` is an array. I think the thing to do here is to use nested `ng-repeat`s:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-repeat="subitem in item.subval">
        <div>{{subitem.attr1}}</div>
        <div>{{subitem.attr2}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kzr90smm/)

---

If you don't like having that extra layer of `div`s, you can define this function in your controller to flatten the arrays:

```
$scope.allSubvals = function() {
    return [].concat.apply([], this.items.map(function (i) { return i.subval; }));
};
```

and then use it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in allSubvals()">
    <div>{{item.attr1}}</div>
    <div>{{item.attr2}}</div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/v3ok4b5g/4/)

Comment: But why it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oongLkf7/1/) check line 58 on the products review list. This is the example from CodeSchool, the products object has the reviews like this example has the subvals.

Comment: @user3277616 That example is doing the same thing as I am doing in the first part of my answer: it's using nested `ng-repeat`s. It has the outer `ng-repeat`: `<div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">`, and the inner `ng-repeat`: `<li ng-repeat="review in product.reviews">`. It does NOT have `<li ng-repeat="review in store.products.reviews">`, which is the equivalent of what you are trying to do.